# Responsive height for images with first child

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I made a script whoch get latest news from my website, but now I have problem with design. I dont know why, but my `height:auto` doesnt work and I want the height to work responsively with width, but thats doesn't happen.

Maybe my idea doesn't work with `height:auto`, because there is one bigger image. I tried to made this with max- & min- height, but that doesn't work either.

I need to made this responsive for all screens, I know about media tags, but in media I want to write some little corrections :)

There is my code, maybe someone can help me!?

HTML

```
<div id="news">

<div id="new_post" style="background-image:url(http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/android-640x480-wallpaper-755.jpg)"><a href="" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></div>
<div id="new_post" style="background-image:url(http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/android-640x480-wallpaper-690.jpg)"><a href="" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></div>
<div id="new_post" style="background-image:url(http://wfiles.brothersoft.com/bd/android_189070-640x480.jpg)"><a href="" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#new_post{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
    background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
}

#new_post:first-child{
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
    height: 205px;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `height: auto;` gets the value of content, in this case 205px. If you want maintain the image aspect ratio use `img` tag instead background image.

Comment: @blonfu you think in that `div` I need to put `img`?

Comment: Also, you should never use duplicate ids. Never. Not even when it seems to work!

Comment: @MrLister ok, thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is very hard achieve to maintain the aspect ratio in any element but with a image is so easy.

```css
.new_post {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.new_post:first-child {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.new_post:first-child a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}

.new_post img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="news">

  <div class="new_post"><a href="" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a><img src="http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/android-640x480-wallpaper-755.jpg"></div>
  <div class="new_post" style="background-image:url(http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/android-640x480-wallpaper-690.jpg)"><a href="" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></div>
  <div class="new_post" style="background-image:url(http://wfiles.brothersoft.com/bd/android_189070-640x480.jpg)"><a href="" style="color:white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get image and get it to your site from those website use this

```
 <img src="http://www.dailymobile.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/android-640x480-wallpaper-755.jpg" alt="Something about image" height="200" width="200">
```

Answer (score 0):

See this: https://jsfiddle.net/psz7xw0n/18/

Instead of targeting first child, I targeted the a tag within the div and displayed it as inline-block in order to give it a height.

Were you trying to have each div float too? The div width of 50% plus the margin made it larger than 50% so they just stacked. In the example I used calc to remove the margin width from the percentage.

```
#new_post{
width: calc(50% - 10px);
float: left;
height: auto;
margin:5px 5px 0 5px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
}

#new_post a{
display: inline-block;
height: 300px;
margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: For some reason first-child only seems to target the first child of the first div but not the rest. I not an expert and couldn't tell you why, all I know is that targeting the a tag works to apply the style to all instances.